# assembly nasm, compute sum of an array of real integers(floats)

Tags: assembly, nasm

the logic of this make sense to me, however it's still giving a segfault any ideas are appreciated...

```
addarray:
    push ebx
    push ebp
    push edi
    push ecx
    push esi
    mov edi, 0      ;initialize counter to 0
    mov esi, 0      ;initialize accum to 0
    mov ecx, 0      ;zero out ecx and edx
    mov edx, 0

    mov ebx, [ebp]  ;moves starting location of array1 into ebx
    mov edi, [ebp+12]   ;moves array size
add_loop:
    mov ecx, [ebx]  ;mov higher order
    mov edx, [ebx+4]    ;mov lower order

    push ecx
    push edx

    fld     qword [ebx]                    ;The second input is now in a floating point register, specifically st0.
    pop     dword ebp 
    pop     dword ebp                      ;The first input is now on top of the system stack (the stack addressed by bytes)

    fadd    qword [ebx]                    ;The first input is added to the second input and the sum
                                           ;replaces the second input in st0

    add ebx,8
    inc edi

    cmp esi, edi
    jz  add_done
    jmp add_loop
add_done:
    mov     eax, summessage                ;Setup to display a message
    call    print_string                   ;Dr. Carter's library
    push    dword 0                        ;Make space on sytem stack for the sum value
    push    dword 0                        ;Ditto
    fst     qword [ebx]                    ;Copy contents of st0 to space currently on top of the system stack
    pop     ecx                            ;Copy 4 MSBs to ecx
    pop     edx                            ;Copy 4 LSBs to ecx
    call    writedouble                    ;Show the 8-byte value
    call    print_nl                       ;Newline

    pop esi
    pop ecx
    pop edi
    pop ebp
    pop ebx
    ret
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you are comparing edi to 0:

```
mov esi, 0      ;initialize accum to 0
...
inc edi
cmp esi, edi
```

Comment: Perhaps you should post a complete example where you pass parameters.

Comment: Hum, what do you mean by a complete example? aren't the parameters(the float values in the array) being passed in when I mov the starting location of the array, then i pop ecx and edx?

Comment: Inside the routine you do, but there is no definition of ebx or ebp, so it's hard to figure out what they are supposed to be. There is no actual array either. There are so much going on that it's hard to see what you want to do without actual data. In addition (no pun intended), you seem to be adding some value to itself: **fld     qword [ebx] fadd    qword [ebx]**

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea would be:

```
    fldz                       ;Load zero into ST0
    mov esi,<address_of_array>
    mov ecx,<number_of_entries>
.next:
    fadd dword [esi]           ;Add float (not double!) to ST0
    add esi,4                  ;esi = address of next float in array
    loop .next
```

For improved accuracy, you might want to sort the array and/or do the additions in order of smallest to largest.

- Brendan

Answer (score 0):

addarray:
    pusha
    mov edi, 0      ;initialize counter to 0
    mov esi, 0      ;initialize accum to 0
    mov ecx, 0      ;zero out ecx and edx
    mov edx, 0

```
mov ebx, [ebp]  ;moves starting location of array1 into ebx
mov edi, [ebp+12]   ;move quantity into edi 
fld qword [ebx]
```

add_loop:
    add ebx,8
        fld     qword [ebx]      ;The second input is now in a floating point register, specifically st0.

```
fadd                 ;The first input is added to the second input and the sum
                     ;replaces the second input in st0
inc esi     ;increment counter

cmp edi, esi    ;compare to see if all values have been added
jz  add_done
jmp add_loop
```

add_done:
    call    print_nl
    mov     eax, summessage   ;Setup to display a message
        call    print_string      ;Dr. Carter's library

```
add ebx, 8        ;increment to not overwrite any values
    fstp    qword [ebx]       ;Copy contents of st0 to space currently on top of the system stack
mov ecx, [ebx]
mov edx, [ebx+4]
```